# How to make date formatting in Django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I apologize for my English already. I did some research, but none of them worked for me. But no data is shown. It appears if I don't type "date:" D d M y ".
I get the data with the API. So all rows are string.

Example:

```
{% for row in activities %}
    <tr>
        <td style="width:30%" class="ads-details-td">
            <div>           
                <p><strong> Date: </strong> {{ row.dateStart|date:"D d M Y" }} </p>         
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

*views.py file*

```
    if user_response.status_code == 401:
        return render(self.request, 'profile.html', {
            'error': 'Beklenmedik bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyin'
        })
    else:
        user_data = user_response.json()
        activities = activity_response.json()

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['first_name']     = user_data['firstName']
        context['last_name']      = user_data['lastName']
        context['activities']     = activities['list']
        context['total_activity'] = activities['total']

        return context
```

*Incoming start date format*

```
'dateStart': '2019-02-05 05:45:00'
```

I will be glad if you help me.

Comment: Can you show how you are building `activities` we can do that at serverside itself

Comment: json data @YugandharChaudhari

Comment: but how can you show it

Comment: could you provide the relevant view code for this variable? because "json data" could be a string or a dict or whatever.

Comment: Yes it comes as a dateStart string. In the theme you want to make it history format. @wfehr

Comment: @Dodiş if you pass the value of `dateStart` as a string (and not as a `datetime`-object) then it won't work, see my answer.

Comment: Yes I understand you. But the data is somewhere. I changed my question, please review again. @wfehr

Comment: maybe a custom template-filter would help you to format the string into datetime and then back to a string. Or you would need to update the `activities` variable.

Comment: Ok I've solved the problem thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good.

I think the problem is that you pass the datetime as a string and not as a `datetime`-object.

If `dateStart` is a `datetime`-object it should work.

From the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

> If **value** is a **datetime** object (e.g., the result of **datetime.datetime.now()**), the output will be the string **'Wed 09 Jan 2008'**.

Edit:

To get a `datetime` for the given string, you can do something like

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime('2019-02-05 05:45:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: It is set to "datetime" in the database. But I draw this data through the API.

Comment: @Dodiş updated my answer for converting datetime-string into a `datetime`-object.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my problem continues.